# Why head() returns IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2 in dask dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dask

I'm pretty new to dask and have an issue I can't resolve myself.

I've got a dask dataframe:

**Dask DataFrame Structure:**

**npartitions=1622**

| Date | UserId | AdNetwork | Revenue | Platform | InstallTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| datetime64[ns] | object | object | float64 | object | datetime64[ns] |

Dask Name: assign, 28302 tasks

I grouped this data by InstallTime and count unique users fro each day to count number of installs by date like this:

`installs = client.persist(total_revenue.groupby(['InstallTime', 'Platform'])['UserId'].nunique().reset_index())`

And got a new dask dataframe like this:

**Dask DataFrame Structure:**
npartitions=1

| index | InstallTime | Platform | UserId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| int64 | datetime64[ns] | object | int64 |

Dask Name: reset_index, 1 tasks

When I want to check what is in dataframe with `head()` or try any other functions I receive the next error:

`IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2`

When I'm trying to use `compute()` I receive the same error.

I haven't find such a problem here or in google, so I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a problem - you can group dask dataframes only by one column.
`installs = client.persist(total_revenue.groupby(['InstallTime'])['UserId'].nunique().reset_index())`
This worked.

Comment: That's not quite true... it's possible to groupby multiple columns, if the `.reset_index()` is done after `.compute()` rather than before.

Comment: I don't know why exactly, but I received the same error with this. And I can't say if it works with one column, cause my computer doesn't have enough power to calculate that - I've got a huge dataframe. But thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This minimal code example for [grouping dask dataframes](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.groupby.html) by multiple columns works:

```py
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from distributed import Client

client = Client()
client

# create dummy dataframe
ddf = dask.datasets.timeseries()

grouped = ddf.groupby(['id', 'name']).x.nunique().reset_index().persist()

grouped.head()
```

I'd recommend separating your chained functions and calling `.head()` on intermediate results to see where the problem is occurring.